# How to remove transition effect from Bootstrap button?

Tags: html, css, button, sass, overriding

I have a Bootstrap button, in which I overrode the styling in my stylesheet because I wanted to change the border radius. Now the button has a transition effect from Bootstrap on it, how can I get rid of it? See the snippet below for the result:

```css
.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 12.313rem;
    padding: 1rem 0.8rem;
    transition: none;
    &-outline-dark {
        color: #000000;
        border-color: #000000;
        transition: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">NOW</button>
```

Comment: Hi, when you say transition. Are you referring to the color it takes when you hover over the button?

Comment: Hi, yes this is what i mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add !important to overrule, i also added the hover part, wasnt clear to me you needed that specificly.

(also to explain: bootstrap has a lot of build-in classes that use specific constructions like button.btn which will overrule the standard .btn class because it's more specific , so using !important will make sure it overrules the class in your case.)

```css
.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 12.313rem;
    padding: 1rem 0.8rem;
    color:#000!important;
    transition: none!important;
    &-outline-dark {
        color: #000000;
        border-color: #000000;
        transition: none!important;

    }
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color:#fff!important;
    color:#000!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">NOW</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, your explantation was very helpful!

Comment: @saturdaysun please try to avoid the usage of `!important` in these cases. You can just put your custom stylesheet to load after bootstrap, and if the specificity of the rules is correct, then do not use !important

Comment: that totally depends on the usecase, it's not logical if you want to override all .btn instances you would have to deal with all the specifc rules seperately by defining their full css paths. you can perfectly use !important inside your custom.css if you know what the consequences are. Alternatively : better you can use the scss version and compile the whole thing as you wish. But thats beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the color changes when you hover over the button, then what you have to do is make use of the `hover` pseudo-class, you can find more information about this in the w3c site here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

In this snippet you can find a possible solution to what you want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/mja1n8ud/